# Slickgrid scroll until last row is in upper part of the Dataview

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is there a way to have Slickgrid continue to scroll down even after the last row is reached so that the last row is viewed in the upper part of the dataview?

Maybe add a css-margin or invisible rows?

Update:

A good comparison would be MS Access table or query views where the last row (or line for adding a row) can be scolled all the way to the top of the view.

Comment: If there is no built in solution I would just; as you approach the end of the scroll, detach the first X number of rows and append them back to the scroll, same when you scroll up (only take from the bottom). Then you have the illusion of continuous scroll in each direction?

Comment: @rlemon, thats a good idea for continous scrolling, what I am looking for though, is a way show the last row with a large emtpy space below it to make it easier to work on the last few rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `leaveSpaceForNewRows` option to `true`.

Comment: Slickgrid is amazing and I plan on using it a lot so thanks. I understand the newrow adds a space, but I would consider a "newrow" the "lastrow" in my question so I would still like to be able to scroll it up higher in the data view.

Comment: If addNewRows is disable and you have the above option set, the last  row should be able to scroll up to the top like you wanted.